# Why are Exceptions not being thrown by DB::statement() on this erroneous query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, prepared-statement

### My Query

I started off with this query. I expected it to insert a new row into `foo` where the column `bar` had a value of `Foo Bar!`.

However, the query would simply fail. As in, nothing would happen. No rows will be inserted into the table, yet I got neither an Exception nor a MySQL error.

```
DB::statement("INSERT INTO `foo` (`bar`) VALUES(':foobar')",
            [
                'foobar' => 'Foo Bar!',
            ]
);
```

---

### My Mistake

After a considerable amount of time, I realize that the `'` marks surrounding `foobar` were unnecessary. This query works as expected.

```
DB::statement("INSERT INTO `foo` (`bar`) VALUES(:foobar)",
            [
                'foobar' => 'Foo Bar!',
            ]
);
```

---

### Not a Syntax Error

Thus, I thought that I must have made a simple Syntax error which caused my query to fail. So I decided to test that with a query that will obviously fail. However, when I tested this query, a `QueryException` **was** thrown.

```
DB::statement("INSERTT INTO `foo` (`bar`) VALUES(:foobar)",
            [
                'foobar' => 'Foo Bar!',
            ]
);
```

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERTT INTO `foo` (`bar`) VALUES(?)' at line 1 (SQL: INSERTT INTO `foo` (`bar`) VALUES(:foobar))

---

### This is Weird

- Since I **was** able to get an Exception thrown at me on a query that is obviously incorrect, it means that I did not turn off `error_reporting` or Exceptions by mistake.
- This also means that my query was not a Syntax error, since I confirmed that a Syntax error throws a `QueryException`.
- Yet, my query must be wrong *somehow*. Otherwise, I would get a row inserted as expected.
- But despite my query being wrong, I do not get any errors to indicate that it is so. It just fails silently.

---

### Reproducing

**Code**

This can be easily reproduced in `routes.php`. The output is `bool(false)`. Yet, no `QueryException` or MySQL error is thrown.

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    dd(DB::statement("INSERT INTO `foo` (`bar`) VALUES(':foobar')",
            [
                'foobar' => 'Foo Bar!',
            ]
    ));
});
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bar` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

---

### My Question

Why does my query fail without any error messages or exception being thrown?

If there is any additional information that I should provide, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: It should have generated a SQL syntax error, are you certain that it didn't?

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, I am certain that no error is generated. Is it possible that it is somehow suppressed in a configuration file? That would be weird though, because my third query *did* generate an error as expected.

Comment: If you are testing this on local host, make sure that your php.ini is set to display errors. I would test another sql query with a glaringly obvious mistake and see if that throws an error.

Comment: @jjones150 Doing a query with a glaringly obvious mistake like my third example does in fact throw an error. Laravel is set to does display errors and display_errors is on in php.ini as well.

Comment: When you tried it before did ':test' get inserted into the test table?

Comment: @jjones150 It did not. `':test'` will not insert but `:test` will.

Comment: Your first query probably didn't fail at all, but rather inserted the _literal string_ `:test` into the table. That isn't a syntactic error, just not what you wanted to do.  check `SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE test = ':test'`. You should find that string has been inserted (not the intended array value)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I thought of that possibility. However, I verified using phpmyadmin that nothing was inserted. I will edit my question to add that information.